# Promise.all triggered before all resolve are executed

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code:

```
  const promises = [];
  const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(manager);
  for (const model of Object.values(tmodels)) {
    promises.push(processTransformModel(model));
  }

  Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => {
        manager.onLoad = function () {
          loadAttachModels();
        };
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // handle errors here
      });

  function processTransformModel(model) {
    new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
      if ( model.url.match( /\.zip$/ ) ) {
        new THREE.ZipLoader().load( model.url ).then( function( zip ) {
          manager.setURLModifier( zip.urlResolver );
          resolve( zip.find( /\.(gltf|glb)$/i )[ 0 ] );
        } );
      } else {
        resolve( url );
      }
    } ).then( function ( file ) {
      gltfLoader.load(file, (gltf) => {
        //do stuff with gltf
    } );
  }
```

There are two gltf files to load, one small, one big. The big one is added first to the array.
I have traced a little bit the code.
Promises array is complete (two elements) before "Promise.all" is called.
But "Promise.all" is always triggered after the small file resolve is executed. The big file resolve is always executed after the "Promise.al" has been triggered.

I can not figure out what is happening.

Comment: `promiseTransformModel()` needs to return the promise.

Comment: `return new Promise(...)`

Comment: Thanks, where exactly do I put the return?

Comment: Did you think to try `console.log(promises)`? You would have seen that it was full of `undefined`. That might have helped you figure it out.

Comment: I just showed you where: right before `new Promise`

Comment: How else do you return things from functions in JavaScript?

Comment: OK, it is clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Working great. Thanks.